# Custom doctrine extension using postgres "OVERLAPS"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I am trying to implement the OVERLAPS function from postgres into a 3.4 Symfony project for date range matching.

I made the following extension:

```
class DateOverlaps extends FunctionNode
{
    public $rangeStart;
    public $rangeEnd;
    public $targetStart;
    public $targetEnd;


    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->rangeStart = $parser->InputParameter();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->rangeEnd = $parser->InputParameter();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->targetStart = $parser->SingleValuedPathExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->targetEnd = $parser->SingleValuedPathExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    /**
     * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        $rangeStart = $this->rangeStart->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        $rangeEnd = $this->rangeEnd->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        $targetStart = $this->targetStart->dispatch($sqlWalker);
        $targetEnd = $this->targetEnd->dispatch($sqlWalker);

        return "($rangeStart, $rangeEnd) OVERLAPS ($targetStart, $targetEnd)";
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
orm:
    dql:
        string_functions:
            overlaps: AppBundle\Driver\DateOverlaps
```

And use it in a simple repository like this:

```
public function findRangedEvents(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('event')
        ->where("overlaps(:start, :end, event.occuringDate, event.occuringEndDate)")
        ->setParameter('start', $start)
        ->setParameter('end', $end);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

But I get errors like

```
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string."
```

I tried many various parser functions but I really can't get to understand what I am missing.

Comment: Most ORM frameworks provide some kind off RAW method where you can insert native SQL might be a better solution it you just could do `where(raw("overlaps(:start, :end, event.occuringDate, event.occuringEndDate)"))` instead of creating a custom parser

Comment: Doctrine providers a raw sql method but I want to use the query builder for this (mapping with entities and stuff)

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by using following condition

```
$qb->where("overlaps(:start, :end, event.occuringDate, event.occuringEndDate) = true")
```